# How to convert hierarchical data from a DataTable to JSON

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, json.net

I have a hierarchical data table as follows which generates a menu and its sub-menus.  The main menu has a `ParentId` of `0`.  Each sub-menu has a `ParentId` referring to the `ResourceId` of another row in the table.

```
ResourceId  DisplayName    ParentId    Url
-----------------------------------------------
1           Home           0           Some Url
2           Student        0           Some Url
3           Staff          0           Some Url
4           Library        0           Some Url
6           StudentAtt     1           Some Url
7           TimeTable      1           Some Url
8           Staff Att      2           Some Url
9           Book Issue     3           Some Url
10          Book Return    3           Some Url
11          Fee Payment    4           Some Url
12          Book fine      10          Some Url
```

I need to convert the data to JSON.  Below is the code I tried out.  I am trying to check if `ParentId` of the sub-menu equals `ResourceId` of the main menu. But the sub-menu is not displayed. (The variable `table` is a `DataTable`.)

```
    var rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
    var result = rows
        .Where(x => x["ParentId"].ToString() == "0")
        .GroupBy(r => new { x = r["ResourceId"] })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            //MenuLevel = g.Key.x,
            MenuDetails = g
                .GroupBy(r => new
                {
                    a = r["DisplayName"],
                    b = r["Url"]
                })
                .Select(detail => new
                {
                    DisplayName = detail.Key.a,
                    Url = detail.Key.b,
                    SubMenu = detail
                        .Where(y => g.Key.x.ToString() == y["ParentId"].ToString())
                        .GroupBy(r => new 
                        { 
                            f = r["DisplayName"] 
                        })
                        .Select(subMenu => new
                        {
                            SubMenuDisplayName = subMenu.Key.f
                        })
                })
        });
```

The result I got is below:

```
[
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Home",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Student",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Staff",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Library",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But the expected result is:

```
[
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Home",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": [
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "StudentAtt"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "TimeTable"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Student",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": [
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "Staff Att"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Staff",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": [
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "Book Issue"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "Book Return"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuDetails": [
            {
                "DisplayName": "Library",
                "Url": null,
                "SubMenu": [
                    {
                        "SubMenuDisplayName": "Fee Payment "
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I also need to display the sub-sub-menu (which has its `ParentId` pointing to the `ResourceId` of the sub-menu).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490607/1454888

Comment: @user1925921 Your expected result is not actually a recursive structure and does not contain all the information from the table (notably, the URL is missing from the submenu, and there is no sub-submenu to handle "Book Fine").  So, are you really looking for the result you posted, or is your true goal to get a fully recursive structure that supports any number of levels of menus and submenus?

Comment: I need a fully recursive structure

Answer (score 2):

The "expected" JSON you posted in your question is not a fully recursive structure, because it is inconsistent from level to level: the submenu items use a different property for the display name than the top menu items, and they do not have URLs or submenu collections themselves.  Also, I think your JSON is more complicated than it needs to be: you don't need the intervening "MenuDetails" arrays, which always have exactly one element.  Instead, I would suggest a simpler structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "DisplayName" : "Top Menu 1",
        "Url" : "/Top1",
        "SubMenu" : 
        [
            {
                "DisplayName" : "SubMenu Item 1",
                "Url" : "/Top1/Sub1",
                "SubMenu" : 
                [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                "DisplayName" : "SubMenu Item 2",
                "Url" : "/Top1/Sub2",
                "SubMenu" : 
                [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "DisplayName" : "Top Menu 2",
        "Url" : "/Top2",
        "SubMenu" : 
        [
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Notice how the JSON is consistent at every level: each menu item has a DisplayName, a Url and a SubMenu, which is a (possibly empty) list of more menu items.  The consistency between levels is the key to a recursive structure.

To make this JSON, we first need a class to represent a menu item:

```
class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        SubMenu = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> SubMenu { get; set; }
}
```

The next step is to translate your flat DataTable into a hierarchical structure.  To do this, I would first build a dictionary of `MenuItems` from the data table, keyed by `Id`:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("ResourceId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Url", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, "Home", 0, "/Home");
table.Rows.Add(2, "Student", 0, "/Student");
table.Rows.Add(3, "Staff", 0, "/Staff");
table.Rows.Add(4, "Library", 0, "/Library");
table.Rows.Add(6, "StudentAtt", 2, "/Student/StudentAtt");
table.Rows.Add(7, "TimeTable", 1, "/Home/TimeTable");
table.Rows.Add(8, "Staff Att", 3, "/Staff/StaffAtt");
table.Rows.Add(9, "Book Issue", 4, "/Library/BookIssue");
table.Rows.Add(10, "Book Return", 4, "/Library/BookReturn");
table.Rows.Add(12, "Fee Payment", 11, "/Library/BookFine/FeePayment");
table.Rows.Add(11, "Book Fine", 4, "/Library/BookFine");

Dictionary<int, MenuItem> dict =
    table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
              .Select(r => new MenuItem
              {
                  Id = r.Field<int>("ResourceId"),
                  ParentId = r.Field<int>("ParentId"),
                  DisplayName = r.Field<string>("DisplayName"),
                  Url = r.Field<string>("Url")
              })
             .ToDictionary(m => m.Id);
```

Then loop through the dictionary, and for each menu item, look up its parent and add that item to the parent's children.  If an item has no parent (its `ParentId` is `0`), instead add that item to a list of root menu items.  It only takes one pass through the dictionary to build the hierarchy in this way.

```
List<MenuItem> rootMenu = new List<MenuItem>();

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    List<MenuItem> menu = rootMenu;
    MenuItem item = kvp.Value;
    if (item.ParentId > 0)
    {
        menu = dict[item.ParentId].SubMenu;
    }
    menu.Add(item);
}
```

Now that we have our hierarchy, it is trivial to serialize it using Json.Net.  (Note the `[JsonIgnore]` attributes in the `MenuItem` class prevent the `Id` and `ParentId` values from being added to the JSON.)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootMenu, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Here is the final JSON produced by the above code:

```
[
  {
    "DisplayName": "Home",
    "Url": "/Home",
    "SubMenu": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "TimeTable",
        "Url": "/Home/TimeTable",
        "SubMenu": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName": "Student",
    "Url": "/Student",
    "SubMenu": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "StudentAtt",
        "Url": "/Student/StudentAtt",
        "SubMenu": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName": "Staff",
    "Url": "/Staff",
    "SubMenu": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "Staff Att",
        "Url": "/Staff/StaffAtt",
        "SubMenu": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName": "Library",
    "Url": "/Library",
    "SubMenu": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "Book Issue",
        "Url": "/Library/BookIssue",
        "SubMenu": []
      },
      {
        "DisplayName": "Book Return",
        "Url": "/Library/BookReturn",
        "SubMenu": []
      },
      {
        "DisplayName": "Book Fine",
        "Url": "/Library/BookFine",
        "SubMenu": [
          {
            "DisplayName": "Fee Payment",
            "Url": "/Library/BookFine/FeePayment",
            "SubMenu": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```